# how to import very large sql file into mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, import

I have a 220GB SQL file. I have to import this into the 355GB Ubuntu MySQL server. There is not enough capacity to import directly from the MySQL server. So I tried to do a remote import from the window with the SQL file. However, it failed several times. I then try to import the 220GB file by a split, but the file size is too big for me. How can I solve this problem? Is division really the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try opening the command line and doing the following?

- mysql -u root -p
- set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
- set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
- SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
- source file.sql
- SET foreign_key_checks = 1

Comment: The SQL file is on the remote server. Can I import the command directly from the remote server? ..with ssh

Comment: Yeah but you need to edit the command in the first line:

mysql -u{user} -h{hostname} -P{PORT} -p{password}

And yes, the command really is like this. So a command like 'mysql -uroot -hlocalhost...' would be correct

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem because of you. After I try, in fact, the problem was very simple. so I bless you